# Middleware redirect user to path if user is invalid

Tags: python, django

Im trying to write a middleware to redirect auth users if they are invalid members.

Here is my code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect


class UserCheckMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):

        #Paths
        inactive_path = settings.INACTIVE_USER_URL

        #First check if the user is logged in
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            #Check if the user has a valid membership
            if not request.user.profile.is_valid_member:

                #Check if the path is the inactive_path to prevent endless redirectloop
                if not request.path in (inactive_path):
                    #Redirect to inactive_path
                    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(inactive_path)
```

Here is my model code:

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    memberend = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)    



    def is_valid_member(self):
        if self.memberend:
            #Return True if memberend is in the future and False if the date is in the past
            return self.memberend >= timezone.now()
        else:
            #Memberend is not set, the user is valid
            return True
```

Anyone know why Im not redirected when I set the memberend date to a date in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called the method.

```
if not request.user.profile.is_valid_member():
```

Method objects themselves are always True.